# Find the rank of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $X,Y\in\mathbb R^n$ be two non zero (column) vectors. Let $Y^T$ denote the transpose of Y. Let A = $X Y^T$. What is the rank of $A$ and what is the necessary and sufficient condition for the matrix $B=I-2XX^T$ to be orthogonal

Answer (score 0):

(1) If $Y\cdot v=0$ then $$ XY^Tv=0 $$

Hence $$ {\rm rank} \ XY^T\leq 1 $$

(2) If $X\neq 0$, $XX^T v=0 $ when $X\cdot v=0$ If $e=\frac{X}{|X|}$, then $$ XX^T e=|X|^2 e $$

That is $$ Bv=v,\ Be=(1-2|X|^2) e $$

$B$ is orthogonal iff for $|v|=1$ and $v\cdot e=0$, $$ (Bv,Be)=(v,e),\ (Be,Be)=(e,e) $$
iff $$(1-2|X|^2)^2=1 $$

So $B$ is orthogonal iff $X=0$ or $|X|=1$